# Scala: Why does extending a trait break `Class.getConstructor()`?

Tags: scala, traits

When a class extends a trait, an invocation of `getConstructor()` that would otherwise succeed then throws a `NoSuchMethodException`.  Why does this happen and what can be done about it?

In the code below, the first invocation of `getConstructor()` returns without error.  The second raises the exception.

```
trait MyTrait

class MyClass(root: String)

object Main extends App {

  val one = new MyClass("foo")
  one.getClass.getConstructor(classOf[String])
  println("so far so good")

  val two = new MyClass("foo") with MyTrait
  two.getClass.getConstructor(classOf[String]) // NoSuchMethodException

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look closer at what happens.

I slightly changed your definition to simplify the generated output. My `Main` object looks like this:

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val one = new MyClass("foo")
    one.getClass.getConstructor(classOf[String])
    println("so far so good")

    val two = new MyClass("foo") with MyTrait
    two.getClass.getConstructor(classOf[String]) // NoSuchMethodException
  }
}
```

After compilation we get the following classes: `App$$anon$1.class`, `App$.class`, `App.class`, `MyClass.class`, `MyTrait.class`.

`MyClass.class` and `MyTrait.class` are trivial and I won't discuss them.

Lets look at interesting classes:

1. `App.class`

Here is the `javap -c` output:

```
public final class test.App {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #16                 // Field test/App$.MODULE$:Ltest/App$;
       3: aload_0
       4: invokevirtual #18                 // Method test/App$.main:([Ljava/lang/String;)V
       7: return
}
```

As we can see, it simply invokes the `App$.main` method.

2. `App$.class`

Here is what's inside:

```
public final class test.App$ {
  public static test.App$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class test/App$
       3: invokespecial #14                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #19                 // class test/MyClass
       3: dup
       4: ldc           #21                 // String foo
       6: invokespecial #24                 // Method test/MyClass."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       9: astore_2
      10: aload_2
      11: invokevirtual #28                 // Method test/MyClass.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      14: iconst_1
      15: anewarray     #30                 // class java/lang/Class
      18: dup
      19: iconst_0
      20: ldc           #32                 // class java/lang/String
      22: aastore
      23: invokevirtual #36                 // Method java/lang/Class.getConstructor:([Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
      26: pop
      27: getstatic     #41                 // Field scala/Predef$.MODULE$:Lscala/Predef$;
      30: ldc           #43                 // String so far so good
      32: invokevirtual #47                 // Method scala/Predef$.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      35: new           #7                  // class test/App$$anon$1
      38: dup
      39: invokespecial #48                 // Method test/App$$anon$1."<init>":()V
      42: astore_3
      43: aload_3
      44: invokevirtual #28                 // Method test/MyClass.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
      47: iconst_1
      48: anewarray     #30                 // class java/lang/Class
      51: dup
      52: iconst_0
      53: ldc           #32                 // class java/lang/String
      55: aastore
      56: invokevirtual #36                 // Method java/lang/Class.getConstructor:([Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
      59: pop
      60: return

  private test.App$();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #54                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: putstatic     #56                 // Field MODULE$:Ltest/App$;
       8: return
}
```

The most interesting part is lines 35 and 39.

Line 35 tells us that in fact we create an instance of the `App$$anon$1` class. It is an auto-generated class representing `MyClass("foo") with MyTrait`.

Line 39 tells how we initialize it. We call the `App$$anon$1."<init>":()V` constructor, but without passing any value to it. Now I'm curious where is the `"foo"` constant?

3. `App$$anon$1.class`

Here is what's inside:

```
public final class test.App$$anon$1 extends test.MyClass implements test.MyTrait {
  public test.App$$anon$1();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: ldc           #16                 // String foo
       3: invokespecial #19                 // Method test/MyClass."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       6: return
}
```

Here we finally see our `"foo"` (in line 1). `ldc` means "load constant"; "#16" is a reference to that constant in a table; the comment says that its type is `String` and value is `foo`.

Line 3 is a call of `MyClass."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V`.

**TLDR** The optimizer hides constants in the constructor of an auto-generated class. So that constructor itself doesn't have any parameters.

**PS**: If we change our code like this:

```
val foo = "foo"
val two = new MyClass(foo) with MyTrait
```

Then we get an auto-generated class with a constructor that accepts a `String` parameter:

```
public final class test.App$$anon$1 extends test.MyClass implements test.MyTrait {
  public test.App$$anon$1(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: invokespecial #17                 // Method test/MyClass."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       5: return
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it goes back to inlining if you make `final val foo = "foo"`?

Comment: What do you mean `final val foo`? `val` already mean you can't change it and `final val foo` not even compiles. In fact compiler may get smart enough at any moment and start to apply some optimization which lead to inlining of this constant. Anyway scala and reflection never go well together.

Comment: `object Test { final val foo = “foo” }` should compile fine and will probably lead to it being inlined again if you try `new MyClass(foo) with MyTrait`.

Comment: This is an outstanding answer and very valuable for learning.  I'm also curious why Scala and reflection never go well together, but I'll leave that for another time.  Thank you!

Comment: @AdamMackler Thanks for your edit. One of reasons why I'm answering questions here is because of that. It helps improve my English. Problem with reflection in scala is that compiler generate a lot of strange and some time unpredictable stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
new MyClass("foo") with MyTrait
```

creates a new anonymous class with a zero-arg constructor (this constructor does `super("foo")` inside) and then creates an instance of that fresh class.

```
classOf[MyClass] eq one.getClass
classOf[MyClass] ne two.getClass
```

Since there's no `String`-based constructor in that new anonymous class, your code fails.

Comment: Fun thing that if you use variable instead of constant then scala will generate constructor with `String` parameter.

Comment: @Oleg Pyzhcov: Not doubting this answer is correct but is this documented somewhere?  Did you learn this by reading source code?

Comment: @talex: are you sure about that?  I changed `val two` to `var two` and the exception is still raised.

Comment: @AdamMackler I mean if you replace `"foo"` to `foo` and declare `var foo = "foo"`.

Comment: @talex Are you sure that's true? I defined `var foo = "foo"` above the definition of `two` and then changed `val two = new MyClass("foo")` to `val two = new MyClass(foo)` and the exception is still raised.

Comment: @AdamMackler I added explanation as my own answer.